# how to make static file in a included file that doesn't reset when the code finishes running the file?

Tags: php, html, validation, php-7, php-5.5

I included a file at the top in the main index.php file and I am having trouble making a variable in it (the included file) constant (static)

 --**More Info**--:  So I am trying to make a form. For each time the user submits successfully, the form should make a new file (with his name and a paragraph of his feedback). So, I made a counter and attached it to the file name, so every-time when submitting.. a new file is made

```
static $counter = 3;
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    // validation code
    if( /* checking that the submission is successful */){

       $file = "feedback". $GLOBALS['counter'] .".txt";
       file_put_contents( $file, $feedback_paragraph );
       $GLOBALS[ 'counter' ] = $GLOBALS [ 'counter' ] +  1;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the counter stays the same. It just increases to 4 and resets back to 3 when submitting again. I don't know why?

**Note:** I know it's not the best way to implement such project, but I still want to understand how php works and why this code is not working?

Thanks everyone. You're such an amazing community!

Comment: this should really use a database, not txt files .. you need to store the counter somewhere, like a db\file php does not have persistent variables.

Comment: what is static for here? Is that inside a class? Or do you want the counter to stay at it's value if the script gets called later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Moaz Eldefrawy I wrote very simple script for you, I know its not optimal but for educational purposes I wrote as much detail as possible, paste this code to your localhost and try it.

This code will record data of the name and feedback in text file as "feedback(counter value).txt", creates counter.txt in your directory for counting purposes.

check your directory and try to open "feedback(counter value).txt" for the recorded data.

hope this helps :)

```
<?php
//initialize
$name = "";
$feedback = "";
$counter_file = "counter.txt";

//Check if name field has input
if(isset($_POST['name']) && ($_POST['name']) != "") {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
}

//Check if feedback has input
if(isset($_POST['feedback']) && ($_POST['feedback']) != "") {
    $feedback = $_POST['feedback'];
}

//if name field and feedback has input call check_counter and record_counter functions
if((!empty($name)) && (!empty($feedback))) {
    check_counter($counter_file);
    record_data($name, $feedback, $counter_file);
}

//assuming no counter.txt is created in your directory attempt to create counter.txt
function check_counter($counter_file) {
    if(file_exists($counter_file) == false) {
        $file = fopen($counter_file, 'a'); //if no counter.txt file in your directory create one
        $counter = 0; //initialize counter from 0
    } else {
        $file = fopen($counter_file, 'a+'); //if counter.txt file exist open that file
        $counter = file_get_contents($counter_file); //read the counter as string
        $counter++; //increment counter
    }

    file_put_contents($counter_file, $counter); //value of counter is recorded in counter.txt
    fclose($file); //close the file
}

function record_data($name, $feedback, $counter_file) {
    $file = fopen($counter_file, 'a+'); //open counter.txt file
    $counter = file_get_contents($counter_file); //read the counter value of file
    $txt = fopen('feedback'.$counter.'.txt', 'a'); //open file, if no file exist attempt to create it

    $data = "name: ".$name.PHP_EOL."feedback: ".$feedback;
    fwrite($txt, $data); //record the name,feed back value as 'feedback$counter.txt'
    fclose($file); //close the file
}
?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>record_data</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>User Name: </td><td><input type="text" name="name" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Feedback: </td><td><textarea name="feedback" /></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td><td><input type="submit"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So I just had to make <b> an external file </b>. I edited a couple of lines and it worked. Really, thanks a lot. you are such an amazing person.

By the way, I know feel guilty because I made the external file manually and only checked and updated the counter in it. However, you, who aren't working on the project, coded all of it. (my laziness never ends!)

Thanks again. Have a nice day!

Comment: @MoazEldefrawy glad that I helped you, no problem I have a similar project, have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1):

I think that's because you are using "static" which resets back your counter to 3.

try this,
1. submit
2. record the $counter to a file.txt
3. increment $counter
4. submit again but this time use the incremented counter in file.txt
5. repeat step 2~4.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is stateless. Every time a request is made, the script is re-run which in your case sets the counter to 3.

If you want to persist the counter between requests you'll need to use some other mechanism for persisting it like a separate file, database etc.

Comment: Yeah I made a new file to store the counter, Thanks to the amazing community. 

**Thank you for answering.**

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to make that variable static for what you seem to be doing. Just having it once on the page should be enough, or declaring it as a global variable where needed(very helpful to look into global more, seems like you are familiar with it somewhat?)

Just a question. I'm not aware if $counter is equal $GLOBALS['counter'] anywhere. Is this happening somewhere?

Ex: $counter = $GLOBALS['counter']; OR $GLOBALS['counter'] = $counter;

Comment: Sorry, forgot to write it. I tried this method (Making a global variable) but it didn't work. Apparently, the value of the variable resets when the files stop running, which I was to idiot to actually realize. Probably too much codding. But, I solved it. 
Thanks for trying to help.